# Handling common dependencies between interdependent modules in Android Studio

Tags: android, module, android-studio, dependencies

Say I have 2 modules in my Android Studio project:

```
---- :A
---- :B
```

Where :A is dependent on B:

```
---- :A ---> + :B
---- :B
```

What complicates things is that both A and B require a library L:

```
---- :A ---> + :B
             + :L

---- :B ---> + :L
```

Initially the gradle files of the modules contained:

**Module A:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':B')
    compile 'com.L:library:1.0.0'
}
```

**Module B:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.L:library:1.0.0'
}
```

But this gives an error indicating multiple libraries provided into the inputList.txt of the dex file:

```
Execution failed for task ':funtainment:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
C:\Development\Android\AndroidStudio\Sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Development\Workspace\Android\AndroidStudio\Funtainment\funtainment\build\intermediates\dex\debug --input-list=C:\Development\Workspace\Android\AndroidStudio\Funtainment\funtainment\build\intermediates\tmp\dex\debug\inputList.txt
Error Code:
2
Output:

UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/nineoldandroids/animation/Animator$AnimatorListener;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

---

So I tried a different structure that worked for me on Eclipse for a similar situation: simply removing the library dependency from module A:

```
---- :A ---> + :B

---- :B ---> + :L
```

Where the gradle files for the modules contain:

**Module A:**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':B')
}
```

**Module B:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.L:library:1.0.0'
}
```

But I get the same error as before!

**Other relevant information:**

- At no point in the entire process was there any java compilation errors(as expected)
- The error only shows up when attempting to deploy(specifically at `:A:dexDebug`)
- The library 'L' above represents 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

---

Is this and Android Studio bug or is this expected behaviour?
How do I allow both these modules to reference this library without leading to multiple libraries being added into the dex and causing errors?

Comment: I had same error yesterday, I was including one api in my project. You must check your `yourproject/apps/libs` folder, there maybe be multiple files with same name. Suppose you have both  `source` and `binary` files in libs folder then remove source files from it and try syncing your project again

Comment: I have ensured that there is no duplicate lib file in my project. A search for any such lib file reveals duplicates only in the *intermediates* folder (generated by Android studio during compilation/deployment operations which i take to be expected behaviour. So this solution doesn't seem to be applicable to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exclude`

```
compile ('great:library:1.0') {
    exclude module: 'lib'
}
```

or

```
compile (project(':mymodule')) {
    exclude module: 'lib'
}
```

Comment: The first method isn't applicable to me since module A requires module B. Your second method seems like the logical solution but I am getting the same error as before on trying your second method :'(

Comment: It worked! After attempting your solution, I manually deleted any copies of the L lib from all `intermediates` folders (by doing a search and deleting the results) then tried to deploy again. I took 5min to deploy, but it worked!